# Global vector data disappearing when executing another function

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I am facing a problem with global a vector. I actually have a vector of vectors of pairs, and I declared it as a global variable.

```
vector<vector<pair<int, float>>> numbers;
```

In the **main** function I do some **push_backs** passing a vector os pairs as an argument, which works just fine.

`numbers.push_back(VectorOfPairs);`

The problem comes out when I call a function that uses **numbers**, which is my vector of vectors.
For some reason, all the content that I stored in the vector gets empty for no reason.
I tried to debbug, and I saw that in function main the size of the vector is actually right, but when I call some function that uses the **numbers** vector, the size changes from any number to **0**.

```
vector<vector<pair<int, float>>> numbers;
//vector declaration 

//suppose I add some elements in the vector in function **main**
//printing the size of the vector works just fine


void matrixVectorMult(){

//if I call this function right after and try to print the size again, it prints **0**.

    printf("-%d-", numbers.size());
    
}
```

I would appreciate any help or hints about how to solve this problem.

https://pastebin.com/vkNNk6Ls

that's my code.

Comment: Vectors don't magically change their size, something in your code is doing this. The obvious tool to use is a debugger. Have you tried that? There's not enough information in the question for anyone to solve the problem for you.

Comment: my guess i sthat you have a different variable called numbers in scope of that function, please show it

Comment: Since I haven't seen your code this is pure speculation, but if you had declared your vector multiple times that would explain what you see. You fill up one vector with data but then you examine a different vector and there is nothing there. Speculation as I said.

Comment: Don't just describe your code, provide a proper [mcve] otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: @john Sorry, that's the code : https://pastebin.com/vkNNk6Ls. It's a little bit confusing I suppose. In line 87 I'm printing the size of the vector, and it works pretty fine. Right after that, I call the function, and printing the size again gives me zero, and yes, I already tried to debbug.

Comment: @Gamechanger It's exactly as I said (and pm100). you have a global variable called `numbers` but you also have a variable in `main` also called `numbers`.

Comment: @john Oh, I see the problem. I actually declared it multiple times.

Comment: @john Yes, exactly like you said. Thank you so much:D silly error I am sorry

Comment: @Gamechanger In a different function you also have a parameter called `numbers`. Using global variables is poor style (generally) but mixing global and local variables with the same name is really poor style.

Comment: @john Yes.. I was not using global variables, I was actually passing the vector to the first functon just like **matrixMatrixMulti** function style. I'll change everything now, thank you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a variable called numbers in main, and you pass this as an argument to those functions. That 'numbers' has nothing to do with the global valiable of the same name.